# Creating Cloud run service with Deployment manager returns "Requested entity was not found." error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to create a Cloud Run service using the Deployment Manager. As there's no native support for Cloud Run resource type, I created a type provider for the Cloud Run API using the following custom descriptor file.

```
resources:
  - name: cloudrun-type
    type: deploymentmanager.v2beta.typeProvider
    properties:
      descriptorUrl: https://europe-west1-run.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1
      options:
        inputMappings:
          - fieldName: Authorization
            location: HEADER
            value: >
              $.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())
      collectionOverrides:
        - collection: namespaces.services
          options:
            virtualProperties: |
              schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#
              type: object
              properties:
                metadata:
                  type: object
                  description: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/ObjectMeta
                spec:
                  type: object
                  description: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#ServiceSpec
                status:
                  type: object
                  description: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#ServiceStatus
            inputMappings:
              - methodMatch: ^create$
                location: PATH
                fieldName: parent
                value: $.concat("namespaces/", $.project)

              - methodMatch: ^(get|replaceService|delete)$
                location: PATH
                fieldName: name
                value: $.concat("namespaces/", $.project, "/services/", $.resource.name)

              - methodMatch: ^create$
                location: BODY
                fieldName: apiVersion
                value: $.concat("serving.knative.dev/v1")

              - methodMatch: ^create$
                location: BODY
                fieldName: kind
                value: $.concat("Service")

              - methodMatch: ^create$
                location: BODY
                fieldName: metadata.name
                value: $.resource.name

              - methodMatch: ^replaceService$
                location: BODY
                fieldName: metadata
                value: $.resource.self.metadata

              - methodMatch: ^(create|replaceService)$
                location: BODY
                fieldName: spec.template.spec
                value: $.resource.properties.spec
```

However, when I run this configuration to create the service using the Deployment Manager, I'm getting the error 404 - Requested entity was not found.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/run1/resources/dm-cloud-run
  message: '{"ResourceType":"<project-id>/cloudrun-type:namespaces.services","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"message":"Requested
    entity was not found.","status":"NOT_FOUND","statusMessage":"Not Found","requestPath":"https://run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/<project-id>/services","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

This is because when the Deployment Manager tries to perform the create operation, instead of calling the location specific service endpoint (e.g. `https://europe-west1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces`), it is using the global endpoint (`https://run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces`) returned by the discovery url, and as stated in the API documentation, the global endpoint supports list method only.

Could someone let me know how to overcome this issue? Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A similar issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065062/create-cloud-run-service-with-deployment-manager) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, Cloud Run is not supported by Deployment Manager ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types)) and there is no good workaround for it.
So I would suggest using [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service) for this purpose instead.